# Extracting images to flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm using an image slider [known as flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). Currently I'm adding images to it manually, but I want to enhance it so that images can be extracted from a specific folder and added to its `<li>` elements. I'm looking for a jQuery function to do so. Is it possible?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t3sgbq5w/

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This php solutions will only work when you upload php files to server, if you won't to run it on your pc you must have installed xampp or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. JavaScript is a client-side technology and cannot do anything on the server. You could however use AJAX to call a server-side script (e.g. PHP) which could return the information you need.
I think you will need php or asp for this, here is code in php:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
        <?php
            $folder = 'images/Galerija'; // chose folder
            $extensions = array('JPG','jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // allowed extensions
            $slika = scandir($folder); // scan folder
            sort($slika); // sort
            foreach($slika as $key => $value) {       
                    $get_extensions = explode(".",$value);
                    $ext = $get_extensions[count($get_extensions) - 1];
                    if (in_array($ext, $extensions))
                    {
                    $title = substr($value, 0,strrpos($value,'.')); // image name
                    echo "<li><img src='".$folder."/".$value."' /></li>"; 
                    }
            }
        ?>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

And you will get this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="images/image.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/image3.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Von Itra, what can i do to use it my html files

Comment: i have xampp but the problem is i'm not sure how to integrate your code and keep my slider design

Comment: mikebrand597@gmail.com

Comment: You can use this code on page as many time you wont, just replace `$folder = 'images/Galerija';` with another folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem before when I'm making an slider, instead of adding a new image manually and editing the code. I write a PHP code that reads all image content inside the folder.

For example I have this folder structure:

```
 > mywebsite
   - index.php
   > images(folder)
     -image1.png
     -image2.png
     -image3.png
```

inside my index.php

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
      <?php $dir_handle='./images/'; 
foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array( '.', '..')) as $file) { echo '<li><img src="./images/'.$file. '" /></li>'; } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the PHP code above reads all image content inside "images" folder. The parsed HTMl should look like this

```
<div class="flexslider">
   <ul class="slides">
     <li><img class="" src="images/image1.png"></li>
     <li><img class="" src="images/image2.png"></li>
     <li><img class="" src="images/image3.png"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

*I hope this will help.*

Comment: dear i have no idea on how to add it to an html file, i've never worked with php

Comment: @mikeb, just copy the code above but change the location of folder, then save your .html file as .PHP file

Comment: Look at my answer, you must have array of allowed extensions, because you don't won't to get everything from folder, like .thumbs or something like that. That will break your flex.

Comment: @Alex Newbie is there a way i can talk to you in chat

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it depends on where you want to get the list of images from. Here are a few scenarios:

**1. Images on your own server (using JS only)**

If you have automatic directory listing (i.e. when you visit a folder without an index.html file, all the files in that folder is listed). You could use an AJAX GET request to this folder, and then parse the content to obtain an array of all the images.

This doesn't require any server-side scripting, but it will take 2 requests to the server (the initial page load, and then the JS will run and get the images).

**2. Images on your own server (with help of server-side script)**

Write a simple server-side script (e.g. PHP) that will get a list of all the images in a folder, and then serve it as part of the page to the client (e.g. in a JS array that is included in the page).

This is faster than **1.** because there will only be a single request to the server. When the user gets the page, it will already have a list of all the images in it.

**3. Images not on your server (using JS only)**

This is generally not possible because of cross-domain security restrictions. I.e. you cannot use AJAX to request a page that is not on the same domain as yours (unless it is specifically allowed by the target server).

**4. Images not on your server (with help of server-side script)**

With this approach you would write some server-side script to get a list of images from another server. The source could be an HTML page. You would get this page and the parse it on your server, and then serve it to your user as part of the final page output.